# After moving the node, from prevRef to newRef how do I update a specific data inside Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use the code below to copy a certain data from `('Pending')` node to `('Approved')` node. It only copies the node including the `username` and the `request_status` of the data. How can I update the `request_status` inside the userid after being copied?

```
var oldRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Pending');
var newRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Approved');

function moveFbRecord(oldRef, newRef) {    
 oldRef.once('value', function(snap)  {
      newRef.update( snap.val(), function(error) {

           if( !error ) {  oldRef.remove();}
           else if( typeof(console) !== 'undefined' && console.error ) {  console.error(error); }
      });
 });    
newRef.limitTolast(1).update({ snap.val().request_status: "Approved" });<<< I tried inserting this code but I think it messes up every code in my .js file
}
```

Where should I put the update line of code?

```
newRef.limitTolast(1).update({ snap.val().request_status: "Approved" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the status in the new node:

```
oldRef.once('value', function(snap)  {
  var data = snap.val();
  data.request_status = "Approved";
  newRef.update(data, function(error) {
       if( !error ) {  oldRef.remove(); }
       else if( typeof(console) !== 'undefined' && console.error ) {  console.error(error); }
  });
});
```

You could even combine the deleting of the old node and the writing of the new one in a single multi-location update. They key to this is that you give the complete path of all data you want Firebase to update:

```
oldRef.once('value', function(snap)  {
  var data = snap.val();
  data.request_status = "Approved";
  var updates = {};
  updates["Request/Approved/"+snap.key] = data
  updates["Request/Pending/"+snap.key] = null;
  firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
});
```

The important advantage of this approach is that either all these updates succeed or none of them do. So there's no chance of any lingering data in the old location.

Comment: You are such a big help to me sir! I owe you a lot! I am so sorry for posting a lot of questions in firebase.

Comment: but sir, there's a problem the request_status goes directly under the `('Approved') node and not under the userid node, it is like this https://imgur.com/a/7VFsS3N

Comment: I copied that from your code. Aren't `oldRef` and `newRef` meant to be pointing to the old data and new location?

Comment: Yes sir, `var oldRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Pending')` and
 `var newRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Approved')`

I tried hardcoding the userId in the `var oldRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Pending').('HARDCODED USER ID')` and `var newRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Approved').child('HARDCODED USER ID')` and it works, I think my problem now is how do i get the unique user  id.

Comment: Yeah, there are a bit too many things missing from your original code there for me to fill in the blanks. How is this code supposed to know the current user? I.e. if it runs in a web page where the user is signed in, that could be as simple as `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`.

Comment: It runs on web admin panel, so I cannot use firebase.auth().currentUser.uid.

Comment: OK, so how is this code supposed to know the current user in that case? There must be some way for it to identify what child node under `/Request/Pending` to move.